# Last block incomplete in decryption while decrypting a file

Tags: java, android, video, encryption, cryptography

I have few AES encrypted videos which I am required to decrypt before playing with ExoPlayer. These videos are going to be included in assets folder of the app while few of them needs to be on SD Card.

I have been using a Utility Class provided to decrypt the videos, but it seems that it's not working properly.

```
static String key = "xxx"; // key should be exactly 16bit long
private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES";

public static void encrypt(File inputFile, File outputFile) throws CryptoException {
    doCrypto(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, inputFile, outputFile);
}
public static void decrypt(File inputFile, File outputFile) throws CryptoException {
    doCrypto(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, inputFile, outputFile);
}

private static void doCrypto(int cipherMode, File inputFile, File outputFile) throws CryptoException {
    try {
        Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
        cipher.init(cipherMode, secretKey);

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
        inputStream.read(inputBytes);

        byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        outputStream.write(outputBytes);

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchPaddingException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new CryptoException("Error encrypting/decrypting file", e);
    }
}
```

For the videos in assets folder, I tried to directly pass the InputStream returned from `getAssets().open(filePath)`, however it gave some error related to padding. So I instead copied the video file to Internal Storage using the following code first

```
public static void copyFromAssets(Context context, String filePath, File outputFile) {
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = context.getAssets().open(filePath);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        copyFile(in, out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LumberJack.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filePath);
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // NOOP
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

The video was there, but since it's an encrypted video I couldn't play it. when I tried to decrypt the extracted video file, I got the following exception -

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption
     at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(BaseBlockCipher.java:853)
     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1502)
     at com.example.utilities.CryptoUtils.doCrypto(CryptoUtils.java:42)
     at com.example.utilities.CryptoUtils.decrypt(CryptoUtils.java:29)
     at com.example.activities.HomeActivity.onVideoPlayButtonClick(HomeActivity.java:107)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.invokeSubscriber(EventBus.java:485)
     at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postToSubscription(EventBus.java:420)
     at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSingleEventForEventType(EventBus.java:397)
     at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSingleEvent(EventBus.java:370)
     at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:251)
     at com.example.viewmodels.BaseDataLevelItemView$1.onClick(BaseDataLevelItemView.java:65)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5210)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21169)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong here. The same decryption code have been in use in the earlier version of the app with same videos, but giving issues now. I have checked with some other answers on Stackoverflow related to the same exception, but most of them was related to encoding issue in the cipher text. I don't have a string here, but a file.

How can I find out, what's wrong here and how can I correct it, if you've already found out the problem?

Comment: Was the file also encrypted on Android? Using the above code? Also, you really should use Inputstream.read() the way the javadocs say you should, checking the return value to see how many bytes are actually read.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Not really sure, but most probably yes.

Comment: Check the return value of `read()`, maybe your file setup is messed up. You need to double check the transformation, the mode, and the IV.

Comment: A wrong key will give the padding error. Do you get the error on files you have encrypted yourself ?  Also .. you ought to fully qualify your TRANSFORMATION (like "algorithm/mode/padding") as different security providers might not use the same defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions from [Ebbe M. Pedersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2196561/ebbe-m-pedersen), I actually tried to encrypt a file and tried decrypting with the same code which worked.
So, it was confirmed that there was some other algorithm or something else was used to encrypt the files. Luckily I found it in the old commits.